# Dropping boxes on top of the listings environment

Tags: beamer, listings, boxes

I was wondering if anyone knew a decent way to drop boxes of text on top of the listings environment. This would be most useful for a beamer presentation that I am currently writing.

Ideally the text underneath the box would not be visible; perhaps it is filled pastel yellow to give the impression that a post-it note has been stuck on top of the listing.

I have played with escaping out of listings and inserting figures/boxes, but none of my attempts have looked right.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I'm unimaginative but could you please provide a [MWE](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)?  What exactly is it you're trying to hide?

Comment: I could imagine that works with tikz, but I am not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: @nickie Basically, I have had to split a code listing over two slides. When I am on the second slide I want to refer to a function that was defined on the first slide. I would like to have a 'post-it note' which appears to remind us of the  signature of this function.

Comment: Are you searching for a differently styled version of [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5423/how-to-open-a-temporary-comics-like-balloon-in-a-beamer-slide)?