# How to change text position in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm new to LaTeX and currently working on my first beamer presentation.I tried to add already proven formulas in a proof as a comment using TikZ since I saw something similar [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5423/how-to-open-a-temporary-comics-like-balloon-in-a-beamer-slide). My current status is this:

```
\documentclass[beamer,compress,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\[\norm{a-b} \tikz[remember picture] \node (a) {$\leq$}; \norm{a} + \norm{b} \]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path<2> (a.south) ++(0,1) node[anchor=north,rectangle callout,fill=blue!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(a.mid)}]  {From $\Delta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\pause \pause
\[\norm{\lambda x} = \lambda \norm{x} \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which results in this:

[image]

This works reasonably well, but I'd like the `\leq` sign not to move up and the box to be under the sign. However, it seems like this isn't an anchor option. I tried looking this up, but the TikZ help seems a little intimidating right now.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305834/36296,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this?

[image]

You can prevent the `\leq` from moving by identifying the baseline in the `\tikz` command before the `tikzpicture`. The callout can be placed below simply by using a negative sign in your relative positioning, such as `++(0,-0.5)`. You can adjust anchors and distances as you like. Code is below.

```
\documentclass[beamer,compress,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\[\norm{a-b} \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(a.base)] \node (a) {$\leq$}; \norm{a} + \norm{b} \]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path<2> (a.south) ++(0,-0.5) node[anchor=north,rectangle callout,fill=blue!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(a.south)}]  {From $\Delta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\pause \pause
\[\norm{\lambda x} = \lambda \norm{x} \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, the trick is to stick in the overlay first.  For the first part, look at the anchor and baseline arguments to the node.

[image]

```
\documentclass[beamer,compress,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Title}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \path<2> (a.south) ++(0,1.2) node[anchor=north,rectangle callout,fill=blue!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(a.mid)}]  {From $\Delta$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \[\norm{a-b} \tikz[remember picture,anchor=base,baseline] \node (a)  {$\leq$}; \norm{a} + \norm{b} \]

        \pause \pause
        \[\norm{\lambda x} = \lambda \norm{x} \]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```